# How to call Upsert with Except in Go (Gin + Bun orm)?

Tags: go, go-gin

```
var newitems = j.RealItem
var items []RealItem
var q = DB.NewSelect().Model(&items).Where("real_item.user_steamid = ?", stid)
res, err := db.NewSelect().Model(&newitems).Except(q).Exec(CTX)
c.IndentedJSON(200, res)
```

I have slice of structs in database and new slice(updated) (j.RealItem as a result of a request), and my goal is delete old(not actual, that not present in new slice) items from database, then update actual items, and insert new.

can't find any docs or examples on how to use bun orm's function Except(ExceptAll), always getting this `runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`

Also tried to create new slice that generated with func

```
    func FindNewItems(old []RealItem, new []RealItem) (genSlice []RealItem) {
        for _, v := range old {
            isFound := false
            for _, w := range new {
                if reflect.DeepEqual(v, w) {
                    isFound = true
                    break
                }
            }
            if !isFound {
                genSlice = append(genSlice, v)
            }
        }
    
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", genSlice)
        return genSlice
    }
```

But i think because of the nested structs it wont work properly

Comment: need more data, can you print the whole traceback, you got in the error message.

Comment: I found a solution (not the best), but it works, it looks like this, I added “status” column in which I indicate new / old and change the status between operations(upsert/delete), so far everything is ok, the only thing is to transfer all operations to transactions